# Adding Nodes to a Binary Search Tree and Traversing it (in order traversal)

Tags: java, tree, this, binary-search-tree, inorder

Code:

```
public class BinaryTree {
    public static int size = 0;

    private static class BST {
        int value;
        BST leftChild, rightChild;

        BST(int value) {
            this.value = value;
            this.leftChild = null;
            this.rightChild = null;
        }

        BST getLeftChild() {
            return this.leftChild;
        }

        BST getRightChild() {
            return this.rightChild;
        }

        int getValue() {
            return this.value;
        }

        void setLeftChild(BST n) {
            leftChild = n;
        }

        void setRightChild(BST n) {
            rightChild = n;
        }

        public void addNode(BST n) {
            if (n.value < this.value) {
                System.out.println("this's value: " + this.getValue());
                if (this.getLeftChild() == null) {
                    // add node n as left child
                    this.setLeftChild(n);
                } else {
                    // otherwise recurse down the left subtree
                    this.getLeftChild().addNode(n);
                }
            }

            // insert somewhere into the right subtree
            else if (n.value > this.value) {
                if (this.getRightChild() == null) {
                    // add node n as right child
                    this.setRightChild(n);
                } else {
                    // otherwise recurse down the right subtree
                    this.getRightChild().addNode(n);
                }
            }
            // duplicate elements
            else {
                return;
            }
        }

        void inOrderTraversal() {
            if (this.getLeftChild() != null) {
                this.getLeftChild().inOrderTraversal();
            }
            System.out.print(this.getValue() + " ");
            if (this.getRightChild() != null) {
                this.getRightChild().inOrderTraversal();
            }
        }
    }

    static BST rootNode = null;

    void addNode(int value) {
        size++;
        if (rootNode == null) {
            // Create rootNode
            rootNode = new BST(value);
        } else {
            // Add newNode to the tree
            rootNode.addNode(new BST(value));
        }
    }

    public void show() {
        if (rootNode != null) {
            System.out.print("In-order traversal: ");
            rootNode.inOrderTraversal();
            System.out.println();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Empty...");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinaryTree object = new BinaryTree();
        object.addNode(5);
        object.addNode(3);
        object.addNode(7);
        object.addNode(1);
        object.addNode(4);
        object.addNode(6);
        object.addNode(8);
        object.addNode(0);
        object.addNode(2);
        object.show();
    }
}
```

I'm still unable to understand how both the addNode method (BST) and inOrderTraversal (BST) method works, especially how the 'this' keyword is used along with dot notation and its recursive steps...

I've tried creating a recursion diagram of the code, but I can't understand how the recursion works here... Can someone please help me in this?

Comment: `this` is simply the node you are currently at, i.e. the one you've called.

Comment: The recursion is simply going node by node by calling the sub trees.